# pythonpath issue? "python2.5: can't open file 'dev_appserver.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ubuntu-9.10, pythonpath

I added this line to my .bashrc (Ubuntu 9.10):

```
export PYTHONPATH=/opt/google_appengine/
```

And then I ran the dev_appserver through python2.5 on Ubuntu like this:

```
$ python2.5 dev_appserver.py guestbook/
python2.5: can't open file 'dev_appserver.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

As you can see, it can't find `dev_appserver.py` even though it's in my `/opt/google_appengine/` directory. Just to make sure it's not a permissions issue I did this:

```
sudo chmod a+rwx dev_appserver.py
```

To check whether it's been added to the system path for python2.5 I did this:

```
$ python2.5
Python 2.5.5 (r255:77872, Apr 29 2010, 23:59:20) 
[GCC 4.4.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> for line in sys.path: print line
... 

/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.5.egg
/opt/google_appengine/demos
/opt/google_appengine
/usr/local/lib/python25.zip
...
```

The directory shows up in this list so I don't understand why it can't be found when I type:

```
$ python2.5 dev_appserver.py guestbook/
```

I'm new to Python so I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python doesn't observe PYTHONPATH when looking for a script you name on the command line. You either need to supply the complete path to dev_appserver.py, or modify the first line of dev_appserver.py (and other tools) to start with "`#!/usr/bin/env python2.5`".

Answer (score 1):

When doing

```
$ python2.5 dev_appserver.py guestbook/
```

what you are passing to the executable `python2.5` is `CURRENT_PATH/dev_appserver.py`.

You have to execute using

```
$ python /opt/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py guestbook/
```

or

```
$ dev_appserver.py guestbook/
```

if `dev_appserver.py` has a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) [for Python](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t343485-shebang-in-cross-platform-scripts.html), that is, [as Nick Johnson points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750496/pythonpath-issue-python2-5-cant-open-file-dev-appserver-py-errno-2-no-su/2750530#2750530), `#!/usr/bin/env python2.5` or `#!/usr/bin/env python`.

Unless you have a very good reason, don't over specify the python version, use the generic `python` command, that is a symlink to the latest version.

Comment: He does have a very good reason: The App Engine SDK currently only supports Python 2.5.

Comment: @Nick: point taken, but whenever I read something along the lines of *I'm new to Python so I would appreciate any help.*, I try and give them a few pointers to things they might pick up without a full understanding.

Comment: Fair enough. (Extra text to make SO happy)